# Unable to play most games on Android QEMU VM on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, android, qemu

So I wanted to set up an android emulator to play Arknights on a Linux Mint desktop machine.

I have libvirtd and I use virt-manager to handle my VMs. I set up both a Android-x86 9 and Android-x86 8.1 VM and got the same error, or rather, lackthereof. Wtih Arknights, it simply crashes, with subsequent launches only resulting in "Arknights keeps stopping", and any simple fixes like updating AndroidWebView don't seem to do anything, since I can't update or uninstall it.

I tried installing and running VOEZ and got a slightly more useful error, instead complaining that it failed to load `libmain.so`. I googled this issue and only found developer logs that suggested I downgrade, so I switched to Android 8.1 and that didn't fix anything. I also tried running anything with `adb` but `adb` does not exist, either in console or in terminal emulator.

I haven't found any good resources for learning QEMU because the gentoo community is as insular and opaque as always, so this could easily be a me issue, but idk.

Here's my VM configuration:

```
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>arknigjts</name>
  <uuid>125914a8-380e-433f-960b-415ffd3c3289</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://android-x86.org/android-x86/8.1"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-i440fx-jammy">hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on"/>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/arknigjts.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="hda" bus="ide"/>
      <boot order="1"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pci-root"/>
    <controller type="ide" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x06" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="network">
      <mac address="52:54:00:69:5b:58"/>
      <source network="default"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice">
      <listen type="none"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
      <gl enable="yes"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ich6">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x04" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <audio id="1" type="spice"/>
    <video>
      <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
        <acceleration accel3d="yes"/>
      </model>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x07" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: have you tried any other Android emulators?

Comment: I looked into a couple, but Nox doesn't have an official Linux build as far as I can tell. I tried installing BlissOS but I couldn't get it to work. I tried looking into Anbox but it seems to be deprecated. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried emulator from Android SDK? It is the "reference" and has adb support. Just download Android SDK and then use SDK manager to enable "Android Emulator" on the "SDK Tools" page.

Answer (score 1):

Because Android x86 isn’t even remotely relevant in the market for actual Android devices, apps may simply not support it. Some apps, especially games, come with native parts (like `libmain.so` here). They must match the platform. Developers can also select to upload multiple APKs to Google Play targeting different devices. Make sure you have a compatible one. For Arknights, I can only find *armeabi-v7a* and *arm64-v8a*.

You could use an emulator that emulates an ARM device to clear that issue. Performance will be significantly impacted though.

Emulators may also not support GPU acceleration, which games often require.

---

There’s yet another hurdle: This game has in-app purchases and is tightly integrated with Google Play. It may also incorporate more DRM (digital rights management), “copy protection” and/or tamper protection.

Working around these is very hard and even if you manage to do it, the next update could block you again.

---

My personal recommendation: Just give up. This is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [android-x86](https://www.android-x86.org/) to it's own partition, and boot directly to it. You will have the best results with GFX, and all hardware addressing, in general.

[Android_x86 - How to set up dual boot with Mint in 5 mins](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=301776)